# How to create DF from vocabulary using not standard delimiters?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I tried to count words frequency via vocabulary:

```
vocabulary = {}

for word in lemmatizer_results:
  if word in vocabulary:
    vocabulary[word] += 1
  else:
    vocabulary[word] = 1
```

after this I tried to convert the results to DataFrame via:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(vocabulary, orient='index', columns=['word', 'frequency'])
```

It would have worked if the structure of the dictionary was like:

```
vocabulary = {'word1': [3], 
              'word2': [34]}
```

but I have structure like this:

```
vocabulary = {'three': 1622,
 'elephant': 66,
 'power': 1070,
 'story': 667,
 'b': 65,
 'paterson': 1,}
```

Can you help me with creation DF from these data? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. With `orient='index'`, the dictionary keys translate to dataframe index, while values translate to data. So you can rename your index, then reset it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(vocabulary, orient='index', columns=['frequency'])\
                 .rename_axis('word').reset_index()

print(df)

       word  frequency
0     three       1622
1  elephant         66
2     power       1070
3     story        667
4         b         65
5  paterson          1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(data={'words':vocabulary.keys,'counts':vocabulary.values})
```

Pandas needs to have the data for each column in a dictionary. It thinks your keys (words) are the column names. You need to give it the column names. You can achieve this by building a new dictionary with elements from your existing dictionary.